# How to select multiple element while hover to single element

Tags: javascript, html, css

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="one">
        <span class="active">Answer</span>     
    </div>
    <div class="two"> 
    </div>
    <div class="three">
        <button class="current"> Please </button>
    </div>
</div>
```

---

Here while I hover to anyone of the class (`active`, `two`, `current`), how to change color to all these class only.

Comment: Using Javascript. Share what you have tried?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a working snippet:

```js
const elements = document.querySelectorAll('.active, .two, .current');

function onMouseOver() {
    for (let i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
        elements[i].classList.add('hovered');
    }
}
function onMouseOut() {
    for (let i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
        elements[i].classList.remove('hovered');
    }
}

for (let i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    elements[i].addEventListener('mouseover', onMouseOver);
    elements[i].addEventListener('mouseout', onMouseOut);
}
```

```css
.hovered {
    color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="one">
        <span class="active">Answer</span>     
    </div>
    <div class="two"> 
    </div>
    <div class="three">
        <button class="current"> Please </button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Basically, you're toggling the `hovered` class on your elements.